# how i disable public holiday list array from 30 day of a month in php?

Tags: php, loops, date, while-loop

suppose public holiday date list is -

```
$public_holiday = array('2018-08-09','2018-08-14','2018-08-26');
```

and I have a loop of 30 day from current date eg-

```
$date = '2018-08-09';
$end_date = '2018-09-08';

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {

    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    $nameOfDay = date('l', strtotime($date));
    echo 'Date-'.$date.'-'.'Day-'.$nameofDay.'<br/>';
}
```

I show the output in table.

I want to disable the row having date of public holiday ouput from while loop.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: `!in_array( $date, $public_holiday )`?

Comment: not working, Actually date is not matching. I don't know why. I am not able to match the public holiday date while looping.

Comment: It's not working because you don't have quotes around the dates! So $date =2018-8-9 = 2001, not '2018-08-09'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = '2018-08-09';
$end_date = '2018-09-08';

$public_holiday = array('2018-08-09','2018-08-14','2018-08-26');
while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    if(!in_array($date, $public_holiday)) {
        $nameOfDay = date('l', strtotime($date));
        echo 'Date-'.$date.'-'.'Day-'.$nameOfDay.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: not working bro, actually $date and $end_date come from database, Here I mention these date for testing. I just asking Only in_array function solve this problem or some another function.

Comment: Oh sry, had the same mistake as you with the third public_holiday in the array. Should work now.